# Apply different color backgrounds for same div class rendered by React

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs

I am rendering some basic text through a JSON file that creates 3 seperate divs with the same class and bootstrap grid system class through React to index.html. I want each individual div to have a different background color. I have written a small jQuery code piece to do this but for some reason it will not render to the individual div class.

My react component (I am rendering this through another React class)

```
var StapleIndividual = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
      var articleNodes = this.props.data.map(function(title) {
        return(
          <div className="category col-md-4">
            <h2 article="title.article" key={title.id}>
              {title.article}
            </h2>
          </div>
        );
      });
    return (
      <div className="all-categories">
        {articleNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

My small jQuery snippet in another file for applying background-color. The first console.log works. It is within the `each` statement that it isn't.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var randomColors =    ["green","yellow","red","blue","orange","pink","cyan"];
  console.log('this is working')

  $(".category").each(function() {
   var len = randomColors.length;
   var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
   $(this).css("background-color",randomColors[randomNum]);
   //Removes color from array so it can't be used again
   randomColors.splice(randomNum, 1);
  });
});
```

Note: I have my jquery snippet script tag below the js file for rendering the react components. I thought this was the issue at first but it isn't.

Can't quite figure this out and any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you set the background color in React? That would be easier.

Comment: First time toying with react and just found their section on inline-styling. Didn't even think of it. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @azium suggested, consider using React itself to render a different color per item.

```
var StapleIndividual = React.createClass({
  colors: ["green","yellow","red","blue","orange","pink","cyan"],
  getColor: function(){
    var len = this.colors.length;
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
    var color = this.colors[randomNum];
    this.colors.splice(randomNum, 1);
    return color;
  },
  render: function(){
    var articleNodes = this.props.data.map(function(title) {
      return(
        <div
          className="category col-md-4"
          style={{backgroundColor: this.getColor()}}>

          <h2 article="title.article" key={title.id}>
            {title.article}
          </h2>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="all-categories">
        {articleNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

I've copied your random color selection code as is, but I'd suggest a different approach since you may run out of colours if you have too many articles. You could simply key in to the colours array with a modulus of your article array index or something so every 4th div is blue every second is green etc.

If you are still curious why your original code isn't working, it may be worth doing some debugging. Where you print out your `console.log`, perhaps log the length of `$('.category')` to see if it's finding anything. If not then it's definitely a render timing issue. Is React render being delayed whilst it waits for the JSON data to load asynchronously?

Good luck :)

Comment: Cheers for this Brandon. First time toying with React and just stumbled upon their section for inline-styling. Had to toy with it a little to get the getColor function to not be undefined but gave me a great headstart. Thanks!